# Assigning values to an array in Rust results in error: 'expected f64, found usize'

Tags: arrays, rust

I want to have an array of 127 `f64` values which are calculated in the `notes[x]` line:.

```
let mut notes: [f64; 127];
let a = 440;
for x in 0..127 {
    notes[x] = (a / 32) * (2 ^ ((x - 9) / 12));
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
5 |         notes[x] = (a / 32) * (2 ^ ((x - 9) / 12));
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected f64, found usize
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler thinks you are assigning a `usize` to `notes[x]` because `x` is inferred as a `usize` as it is used for indexing `notes` and it is a part of the right-hand side expression. If it didn't contain `x`, the expression's return type would be inferred as an `i32` because it contains `a` which doesn't have an explicit type and the default integral type is `i32`.

To make the right-hand side expression return `f64`, you need to indicate that its components are `f64` and perform a few casts; you will also need to change `^` to [`powf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.powf) (assuming you want to perform a power):

```
let a = 440f64;

notes[x] = (a / 32.0) * 2f64.powf((x as f64 - 9.0) / 12.0);
```

This is not enough, though:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `notes`
 --> <anon>:5:9
  |
5 |         notes[x] = (a / 32.0) * 2f64.powf((x as f64 - 9.0) / 12.0);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `notes`
```

In order to solve this issue, you need to initialize the `notes` array, e.g. with zeros:

```
let mut notes: [f64;127] = [0f64;127];
```

Comment: I assume `^` meant `pow`.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that; I'll include this.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Rust is still very new to me, a bit hard to transition from java backgrounds.

Comment: @VikingPingvin probably worth noting that an array is unlikely to buy you much here; you may want to move to a vector. [Then you can use nice methods like `map` and `collect`](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=b85b1121aab7b423ed0dbf866fad5f0a&version=stable).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you don't want integer division. `440/32` takes on `13` instead of `13.75` and the same problem in `(x - 9) / 12`. So use strictly float types.

```
let mut notes:[f64;127] = [0.0; 127];
let a = 440.0;
for x in 0..127{
    notes[x] = (a / 32.0) * ((x as f64 - 9.0) /12.0).exp2();
}
```